# Triggering PaintEvent in a "hidden" QGLWidget without a layout?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QGLWidget that shares context with 5 other widgets that can change layouts and locations dynamically. This shared widget is something that I dont want to be shown because it doesnt fit in anywhere. The only way I can use it, however, is by doing a "static" one time VBO generation in its initializeGL().

How do I use its paintEvent as normal with this shared widget not being attached to a layout or visible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it appear seamless you attach the shared QGLWidget only onto the QMainWindow, then show() the QMainwindow so the initializeGL() gets called. Basically you show the QMainwindow earlier than normal.